# How to configure Log Target in datapower using SMTP server

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have tried configuring Log Target using Fake SMTP server and i am successful in that Now i am trying to do the same with Actual SMTP server (gmail and outlook) but i am not able to send and receive error mails in my inbox. I have configured SMTP Configuration and Log Target Configuration in IBM Datapower. Can you guys help me out doing the same[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwqzU.png)

Comment: This question is probably off-topic on StackOverflow. For network related issues, check http://www.serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks right on your screen image except

SMTP Client Domain would be just gmail.com

and you configured the SMTP Server Connection to handle auth if needed.

Otherwise it all looks good.